# TigerVNC/fltk doesn't handle screen resolution properly

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm trying to connect from macOS X Catalina on a Centos7 with the tiger-vnc client from Homebrew.

When I have a screen plugged in, no problem. When no screen is plugged in, something very funky happens: the remote window is resized to take a quarter of my screen (lower left), but the mouse works as if the screen was full screen! i.e. I have to multiply by 2 everything I do with the mouse to act on the lower left hand side window!

I've tried different combinations of the screen options (which you access by doing F8 or fn-f8).

Any idea what is going here?

Here is how I setup the vncserver on the host:

```
vncserver :1 -localhost -name my-session -geometry 1600x1200
```

(I have tried without the geometry parameter.)

here is how I access it from my mac:

```
vncviewer me@host.domain :1
```

**Partial answer**:

This is a problem with FLTK as [this bug](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/37872) reports. The fix is to revert to older versions of FLTK with Homebrew (there are numerous posts about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53837861/brew-list-and-install-specific-versions-of-formula) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43538993/homebrew-list-available-versions-with-new-formulaversion-format) for example). But it looks like older versions of FLTK are not working with Catalina (at least the ones which you get with these methods). So this is probably unsolvable as long as FLTK isn't updated.

**A solution that actually works**

Forget about using homebrew, download TigerVNC [from here](http://tigervnc.bphinz.com/nightly/) and install it.

You can now go into `/Applications/TigerVNC\ Viewer 1.10.80.app/Contents/MacOS` and execute:

```
./TigerVNC\ Viewer -via me@host.domain :1
```